# Why does BitmapFactory decodeFile return null?

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I've been following the Android developers guide to create an app that uses an existing camera app to take some photos. Next I'm trying to put them into an imageview using this part of the guide https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskScalePhoto
but BitmapFactory decodeFile is returning null. I simplified it to the following code but it gives the same result.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

mCurrentPhotoPath was set to `image.getAbsolutePath()` and an example is
storage/emulated/0/Android/data//files/Pictures/JPEG_20170503_102533_2060032401.jpg

I can hard code the value of mCurrentPhotoPath to a known photo and I still get null.

However if I replace that with
storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20161124_145814981_HDR.jpg
(a photo created separately using my phones normal camera app) then it works.

I have

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

in my manifest. The 2 files have the same permissions and are about the same size. I can copy them elsewhere and they seem to be valid jpeg files.
Any ideas what could be going on?

I've looked through many posts and tried a number of things including the variation below but I get the same result.

```
File dest = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
FileInputStream fis = null;
fis = new FileInputStream(dest);
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
smallPhoto.setImageBitmap(img);
```

Comment: Paths start with `/`. I would expect all of yours to fail, including the one that you say works.

Comment: Probably passing the wrong BitmapOptions.

Comment: the first path looks malformed, it has double `//` in the middle

Comment: It returns null if the bitmap would become too big for available memory. Try an image with smaller resolution. Not so much the file size matters as the resolution.-

Comment: Hard coding at the moment; seems to work with or without the /. Correct that post has // but somehow that's my mistake: actual code does not have //. One image works with no BitmapOptions set and no scaling, other doesn't. Thanks all though, will try lower resolution.

Answer (score 0):

you must scale your image through the options method.

```
 File dest = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
 FileInputStream fis = null;
 fis = new FileInputStream(dest);
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inSampleSize = scale;
 Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, options);
 smallPhoto.setImageBitmap(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

I now see that the procedure I'm using to take a photo is creating 2 files: the actual image in storage/emulated/0/DCIM and a file created in the app's storage area on the phone, so the problem seems to be in how I'm creating/saving the image. I'm using code here https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath
but have presumably got something wrong. I'll close this, look again and raise a new question if necessary.